# gulp sourcemaps doesn't update correct after pipe uglify and then gulpRegexp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

i have problem when i use pipe uglify and then gulpRegexp 
the sourcemap doesnt update correctly.

i check in chrome debugging tool and i cant put breakpoint in my js file. if i use only one of them uglify or gulpRegexp it's work ok

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
concat = require("gulp-concat") ,
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
replaceSourcemaps = require('gulp-replace-with-sourcemaps'),
gulpRegexp = require('gulp-regexp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('default', function () {    
gulp.src('js/*.js')
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
.pipe(concat('all.js'))
 //if i remove uglify or gulpRegexp it work fine
.pipe(uglify())  
.pipe(gulpRegexp(/(".*?")/g, '$1' + '\n'))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write(''))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

any idea?

thanks alot

Comment: flipping the order help?

Comment: the uglify wil destroy my replace :(